# Spring 3 pet clinic example uses ${owner.new}, in the JSTL EL where can I read about out about .new operator?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Spring 3 pet clinic example uses `${owner.new}`, in the JSTL EL where can I find out more about where the .new comes from and what spec it is a part of?  Ive seen empty and not empty operators/ reserved words but not .new until now in the Spring 3 pet clinic example.hers is the line im questioning:

```
<h2><c:if test="${owner.new}">New </c:if>Owner:</h2>
```

located in the ownerForm.jsp file in the spring 3 pet clinic sample application.

Comment: Thanks Albert...Even i had the same doubt

Answer (score 4):

In the expression `${owner.new}`, the dot operator is used to access a property named `new` of the object referenced by the `owner` identifier. The EL accesses object properties using the Java beans conventions, so a getter for this property (typically a method named `getXxx()` or... `isXxx()` for a `boolean`) must be defined in order for this expression to evaluate correctly.

And if you look at `org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Entity` (a simple JavaBean superclass used for all persistable objects), guess what, you'll see:

```
public boolean isNew() { return (this.id == null); }
```